# Error:Multiple annotations found at this line: - error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix - Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

Tags: android-layout

I m just a biginner for andriod app devlopment. I am trying to create a editable text area in Linear layout with following code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >   

   <EditText andriod:id="@+id/edit_message" 
     andriod:layout_width="wrap_content"    
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         andriod:hint="@Srting/edit_message">
   </EditText>           
  </LinearLayout>
```

But when saving the xml code it gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

`<EditText andriod:id="@+id/edit_message" 
     andriod:layout_width="wrap_content"

     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         andriod:hint="@Srting/edit_message">
</EditText>`

**Srting should be string**